# Add user to SSH group safe?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, sudo

I want to control who can log in via SSH on my server. Is it safe to add the group 'ssh' to the users who are allowed to login in?

I see some distros use system groups in the user's ID and others recommend creating new groups. For example, some users will have the `sudo` group and other distros recommend creating a new group `gSudo` and adding it to the sudoers file.

Comment: I am not sure off hand what the ssh group is for.. but it's not for that. So I suppose if you want to create a group, you should create a new user group. But you could also add individual users instead. So, you can set ssh up as a whitelist i.e. to not allow anybody except, those users or groups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of `ssh` group was described on [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252069/121504). There is no gain by adding user to `ssh` group, because the group is used only for pre-authentication process.

If you want to use a group to limit who can log in to your server using `ssh`, create a group `sshuser`,  add `AllowGroups sshuser` to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart your `ssh` service.